# Understanding starting a thread and possible data races involved

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In Practice and now I'm at the section about synchronizers. He described `latches` as a kind of synchronizers and provided a typical use-case for `CountDownLatch`:

```
public class TestHarness{

    public long timeTask(int nThreads, final Runnable task){

        final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

        for(i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
           Thread t = new Thread(){
              try{
                  startGate.await();
                  try{
                      task.run();
                  } finally {
                      endGate.countDown();
                  }
              } catch (InterruptedException ignored){ }
           };
           t.start();   // <--- Here
        }

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        startGate.countDown();
        endGate.await();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return end - start;
    }

}
```

The use-case of latches is perfectly clear in this example, but the question is

***Why the program may be considered as a correctly synrhonized one***?

Accoridng to [JLS 17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all
>   resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be
>   predicted by the memory model.

some reorderings may occur. We don't have any explicit synchronized blocks here. Why isn't it possible, for example, that a compiler produces a code where `startGate.countDown` comes before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the original does not guarantee all threads are ready before starting as @St.Antario alluded. It does guarantee no threads will start before the code `long start = System.nanoTime();`

Some threads can start running before all threads are initialized. I think if the code wanted to stop all threads from starting until they were all ready, the code would have to be:

```
public class TestHarness{

public long timeTask(int nThreads, final Runnable task){

    final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);//Changed this from 1
    final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

    for(i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
       Thread t = new Thread(){
          try{
              startGate.countDown(); //Reduce the latch count by 1
              startGate.await(); //Once the last Thread is ready, this will continue
              try{
                  task.run();
              } finally {
                  endGate.countDown();
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException ignored){ }
       };
       t.start();   // <--- Here
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    endGate.await();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    return end - start;
  }

}
```

Here is a Test harness that shows the init and start sequences in the original code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class TestHarness{


    public long timeTask(int nThreads, final Runnable task) throws InterruptedException{

        final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

        for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
           Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                  try{
                      System.out.println("Init");
                      startGate.await();

                      try{
                          task.run();
                      } finally {
                          endGate.countDown();
                      }
                  } catch (InterruptedException ignored){ }
               };

            });

           t.start();   // <--- Here
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        startGate.countDown();
        System.out.println("Open Gate");

        endGate.await();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return end - start;
 }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestHarness().timeTask(10, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              System.out.println("Am Running");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you run the code, sometimes you will see this:

```
Init
Open Gate
Am Running
Init
```

This means some Threads may not be ready/created before startGate.countDown() is called.

Comment: That's just simply wrong. Read the Javadocs for `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Ah, didn't see you increased the permissions for `startGate`. Well yes, this would work as well.

Comment: But I can't seem to remove my downvote because of some arbitrary time limit unless you edit your post.

Comment: Ok, edited it to add a comment so its easy for people to see the edit to the increase in startGate.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, now I see it work, but it doesn't explain why the original example does... and why

Comment: @St.Antario I'm not sure the original is going to work under all scenarios. If you get any delay before startGate.await() in the original, the first thread may start before the last thread is ready.

Comment: @DanielMoscufo Your code is more readable. But it is not (more) efficient. The above given code is the right implementation and would work fine.

Comment: @shanmunga, see the Test harness code I posted for the original. I think ops original question was right, there is a bug in the code as he thought.

Comment: @shanmuga It's at least arguable, because there's no sufficient synchronization (As I see it...)

Comment: @St.Antario Why do you think so?

Comment: @shanmuga What's preventing the compiler from reodering the loop and the timing-related code? I don't see... If it happens, the original programm won't work correctly.

Comment: @shanmunga run the test harness I posted. Here you can see that a thread can start before another thread is initialized.

Comment: @St.Antario I see it now. Yes it would be a problem due to compiler optimizations.

Comment: When you're talking about compiler, are you referring to `javac` or `JIT`? Also there's talk about "lack of synchronization" which to me seems wrong. Just because there aren't `synchronized` blocks doesn't mean there aren't established `happens-before` relationships. I'd like to hear from one of the resident smartypants about this, after all it's not like the example code was written by some hobo off the streets :)

Comment: @Kayaman I agree. It depends on the intent of the original code. Have updated my answer to point out that the original code ensures no threads have started before the start time is assigned. Whether it intends to stop any thread from starting before all are ready is unknown.

Comment: @Kayaman, In the book its states: "The starting gate is initialized with  a  count  of  one;  the  ending  gate  is  initialized  with  a  count  equal  to  the  number  of  worker  threads.  The  first  thing  each  worker thread does is wait on the starting gate; **this ensures that none of them starts working until they all are ready to  start.**" From this it would suggest it is a bug.

Comment: @Kayaman `javac`. JMM mentioned the concept of so-called _intra-thread semantic_. Maybe this is the case? I mean if the reodering occurred it would violate the intra-thread semantic in some way...

Comment: @St.Antario Well `javac` does practically nothing to optimize the code. It certainly won't reorder operations.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't it possible, for example, that a compiler produces a code where startGate.countDown comes before the loop.

It is possible.  It's just that `countDown()` won't finish until the other threads have all called `countDown()` as well.

Comment: So, that would render the example incorrect, as that the workers might not start simultaneously.

Comment: Why would it get reordered as it internally uses `Sync`?

Comment: @St.Antario, why would that render the example incorrect?

Comment: @SMA, the threads don't actually have to start immediately.  That can (and often does) happen somewhat later.

Comment: Do you mean until other threads have called `await()`? `startGate` and `endGate` don't have any relationship here (besides the logical one), do they?